# How to change a div class on click (tap) for iPhone mobile web

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, html

I have 4 buttons, built as divs.  These divs control the show/hide state of other divs on the same page.  The divs currently contain copy points inside of each div(button).  The background color of each div needs to change to a "selected state" once the user selects a div(button).  This can also be referred to as an "active/inactive" state.  I want the user to know which div(button) they have selected by changing the background color as well as the text color within each div.

I would like to accomplish this with CSS, Javascript, or any other suggestion you guys may have.  I am currently using gradient backgrounds for the div(buttons) in my css.

I have looked on the site and can not find this being done with 4 tabs, buttons, divs.  Only two.  This is my first post, so i apologize if i am not clear.  Thanks in advance

Here are my div (buttons) HTML:

```
<div id="row1">
    <a id="buttonToggle1" href="#" ><div class="width145 paddingFloaterCell floatlft productSelectedBtn btnBorderBtm"><span class="bby_blue"><strong>Product Name</strong></span><br><span class="red_text"><strong>$100</strong></span></div></a><a id="buttonToggle2" href="#" ><div class="btnBorderLft width146 paddingFloaterCell floatrt productNotSelectedBtn"><span class="textWhite"><strong>Product Name</strong></span><br><span class="textYellow"><strong>$100</strong></span></div></a>
</div>

<div id="row2">
    <a id="buttonToggle3" href="#" ><div class="width145 paddingFloaterCell floatlft productNotSelectedBtn"><span class="textWhite"><strong>Product Name</strong></span><br><span class="textYellow"><strong>Sale: $100</strong></span></div></a><a id="buttonToggle4" href="javascript:showonlyone('productSelected4');" ><div class=" btnBorderLft width146 paddingFloaterCell floatrt productNotSelectedBtn"><span class="textWhite"><strong>Product Name</strong></span><br><span class="textYellow"><strong>Sale: $100</strong></span></div></a>
</div>
```

"
Some of the CSS:

```
.productNotSelectedBtn{
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,57,98) 20%, rgb(42,91,126) 60%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,57,98) 20%, rgb(42,91,126) 60%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,57,98) 20%, rgb(42,91,126) 60%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,57,98) 20%, rgb(42,91,126) 60%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,57,98) 20%, rgb(42,91,126) 60%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left bottom,
left top,
color-stop(0.2, rgb(0,57,98)),
color-stop(0.6, rgb(42,91,126)));}
.productSelectedBtn{
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(231,231,231) 42%, rgb(254,254,254) 71%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(231,231,231) 42%, rgb(254,254,254) 71%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(231,231,231) 42%, rgb(254,254,254) 71%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(231,231,231) 42%, rgb(254,254,254) 71%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(231,231,231) 42%, rgb(254,254,254) 71%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left bottom,
left top,
color-stop(0.42, rgb(231,231,231)),
color-stop(0.71, rgb(254,254,254)));
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 5px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000000;
box-shadow:         inset 0 0 5px #000000;}
```

Comment: As an aside, you should always have the non-vendor-prefixed rule listed last (`linear-gradient`).

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial with jQuery:

```
jQuery('#row1 a, #row2 a').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('div').toggleClass('productNotSelectedBtn productSelectedBtn');
});
```

You basically just swap css classes for each div, you toggle `productNotSelectedBtn` and `productSelectedBtn`

​Try it out on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/vHyHz/2/